# Percona: Diffs cannot be detected because no slaves were found

Tags: mysql, perl, database-replication, high-availability, percona

I am trying to use tool Percona to see inconsistencies of data on Master-Slave MySQL instances. Master and Slave are on different servers. I tried to run pt-table-checksum using recursion method as process-list below is the error:

[image]

I tried to run pt-table-checksum using recursion method as dsn method below is the error:

[image]

bxxmysqld1 master : 10.200.213.32 : bxxxxd02my1

bxxmysqld2 slave : 10.200.213.92  : bxxxxd02my2

I am not sure what configuration I can try now. Any suggestions and ideas are helpful. Please suggest if I can try other recursion method. Thank you!

References: 
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html

https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-toolkit/35307-pt-table-checksum-connect-to-a-slave-without-ip-connection

https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-toolkit/16772-pt-table-checksum-percona-toolkit-2-2-7-1-not-able-to-find-the-slaves

Comment: Also made changes in my.cnf by putting information of slave IP and port for fields `report_host` and `report_port=3306` and restarted the service. It did not work.

Follwed

http://www.fromdual.com/check-and-fix-mysql-replication-inconsistencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kjosh,

Have you tried connecting to your slave from master? in first example seems user might not have permissions to connect to slave, try this: 
mysql -uptc -psecret -h10.200.213.92 to see if you can connect, if not then you need to provide access to master host (i.e. via grant command allowing host 10.200.213.32) 
In second option you need to remove socket options because they are only for localhost connections, still the recommendations to review if host is allowed to connect to slave applies. 
Hope this helps.

Francisco.

Comment: I could not connect to slave, working with infrastructure team on that. As soon as they grant the access I will try running pt-table-checksum cmd without socket options. Will keep you posted, Thanks for you help @FranciscoBordenave

Comment: I am able to connect slave after making some changes in infrastructure. I also removed socket options from dsns table. However, it did not work. I dont see the pt-table-checksums output. Please find the below code.

Comment: `mysql> select * from dsns;
| id | parent_id | dsn                            |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------+
|  1 |         0 | h=10.200.231.22,u=ptc,p=secret |
|  3 |         0 | h=10.200.231.82,u=ptc,p=secret |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)` @FranciscoBordenave

Comment: `mysql> exit
Bye
mysql@server>./pt-table-checksum h=10.200.231.82,P=3306,u=ptc,p=secret --recursion-method=dsn=D=percona,t=dsns
mysql@server:/u01/app/mysql/product/bmirschd02my1/percona-toolkit-2.2.16/bin>mysql -uptc -psecret -h10.200.231.82
mysql>
`
@FranciscoBordenave